# Teams connector - Actions in message cards

Tags: webhooks, microsoft-teams, office365connectors

I am currently working on extending my existing MS Teams Connector with some `potentialActions`. In the past I have successfully used the `openURI` action. 
Now I am trying to use the 'Custom Incoming Webhook' to gather some information on the format/amount of information sent to the `target`, when the user interacts with the card.

**EDIT 05/10:**

I now switched to using a registered connector (fdfa8471-96a7-411a-a6ad-f402709e2165). The MessageCards are successfully sent to the Teams Chat and show the configured Actions. When trying to use the action, I receive the following error (in the console):

```
{  
   "data":{  
      "errorCode":"Forbidden",
      "message":"An unexpected error(Type = Forbidden) occurred. Please try again."
   },
   "status":403,
   "config":{  
      "method":"POST",
      "transformRequest":[  
         null
      ],
      "transformResponse":[  
         null
      ],
      "url":"https://teams.microsoft.com/api/mt/emea/beta/users/connectors/19:a5dd279d9bc744cca4286a6a0fadc975@thread.skype;messageid=1557483063258/1557483063258/executeAction",
      "data":{  
         "inputParameters":[  
            {  
               "id":"comment",
               "value":"pls :)"
            }
         ],
         "actionId":"7d66186f-ee1a-4612-a4c7-5c2099758db9",
         "potentialAction":"{\"@type\":\"HttpPOST\",\"@id\":\"7d66186f-ee1a-4612-a4c7-5c2099758db9\",\"name\":\"OK\",\"target\":\"https://*******.ngrok.io/api/v1/msteams/connectorAction/comment\",\"headers\":[],\"body\":\"comment={{comment.value}}\",\"bodyContentType\":\"\"}",
         "name":"action/connector",
         "integrationId":"gcor97uz3c",
         "meta":"{\"connectorSenderGuid\":\"fdfa8471-96a7-411a-a6ad-f402709e2165\",\"providerAccountUniqueId\":null,\"connectorConfigurationAlternateId\":\"a092b30d74ee436b9409be217b00e6c2\"}",
         "clientInfo":{  
            "locale":"en-gb",
            "country":"gb",
            "platform":"Web",
            "clientVersion":"1415/1.0.0.2019050223"
         }
      },
      "headers":{  
         "X-Skypetoken":"pii",
         "Authorization":"pii",
         "Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*",
         "Content-Type":"application/json;charset=utf-8",
         "X-RingOverride":"general",
         "x-ms-scenario-id":"1325",
         "x-ms-request-id":"d0be16f6c0e745a5c9d3fd9d3c5d09ec_1326",
         "x-ms-user-type":"user",
         "x-ms-client-type":"web",
         "x-ms-client-env":"msteams-web-prod-euwe-01",
         "x-ms-client-version":"1415/1.0.0.2019050223",
         "x-ms-session-id":"d0be16f6-c0e7-45a5-c9d3-fd9d3c5d09ec"
      },
      "counter":"ext_actionable_card_http_post",
      "decrementNetworkRequests":null,
      "hostName":"teams.microsoft.com"
   },
   "statusText":""
}
```

The `target` url set in the action matches the one registered with the connector. In receive no POST to my tunnel, so I assume the error is in the backend.

Can you please point me to some helpful information regarding this issue?

Gelx

Comment: Did you enabled actions on your Connector cards in [Connector portal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLtJq.png)? Could you please share you App Manifest which we could try at our end?

Comment: As I stated I was using a 'Custom incoming Webhook' to get some information on the data-format that would be received when actions are dispatched. 
Will try with a 'real' connector now.

Comment: I just updated the connector configuration on `outlook.office.com/connectors` and registered the actions URL. 
I also switched all the urls to my tunnel url (back from previous staging): [manifest.json](https://gist.github.com/Ge-lx/f816d67db0a2b92f6df92699bb673e7a)

I cannot register the connector in Teams: [Error message](https://gist.github.com/Ge-lx/f9684c64b7625c862ac941425ab6ae95)

I encountered this behaviour before and it fixed itself by waiting a few hours. Is the connector configuration slow to update or am I missing something?

Comment: Please note though that the tunneled site is pretty slow due to being unpackaged and might not be available again in a few hours.

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT I updated the above post and am facing a different issue now. Could you please have a look?

Comment: Ngrok has a free account which gives you one URL which does not expire. Could you please sign up and share the URL? I'll take a look at this. Also, if possible please share the fiddle trace, to see if there are other failures before response you shared.

Comment: Also, Could you please share your [channel link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJxbD.png)?

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT I was able to resolve this issue. It was caused by the connector being registered with a different account (tenant) than the user that was used to test the app in teams. 
Is this indeed the case? Because when I used the user I registered the connector with, it worked like a charm. This should really be pointed out in the developer documentation ;)